# How to custom marshal map keys in JSON

Tags: json, string, dictionary, go, slice

I can't understand a strange behavior of custom marshal `int` to `string`.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Int int

func (a Int) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    test := a / 10
    return json.Marshal(fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", a, test))
}

func main() {

    array := []Int{100, 200}
    arrayJson, _ := json.Marshal(array)
    fmt.Println("array", string(arrayJson))

    maps := map[Int]bool{
        100: true,
        200: true,
    }
    mapsJson, _ := json.Marshal(maps)
    fmt.Println("map wtf?", string(mapsJson))
    fmt.Println("map must be:", `{"100-10":true, "200-20":true}`)
}
```

The output is:

```
array ["100-10","200-20"]
map wtf? {"100":true,"200":true}
map must be: {"100-10":true, "200-20":true}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iiUyL2Hc5h_P

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the expected outcome, which is documented at [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> Map values encode as JSON objects. The map's key type must either be a string, an integer type, or implement encoding.TextMarshaler. The map keys are sorted and used as JSON object keys by applying the following rules, subject to the UTF-8 coercion described for string values above:
>
> ```
> - string keys are used directly
> - encoding.TextMarshalers are marshaled
> - integer keys are converted to strings
> ```

Note that map keys are handled differently than values of properties because map keys in JSON are the property names which are always `string` values (while property values may be JSON text, number and boolean values).

As per the doc, if you want it to work for map keys as well, implement [`encoding.TextMarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler):

```
func (a Int) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    test := a / 10
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", a, test)), nil
}
```

*(Note that `MarshalText()` is ought to return "just" simple text, not JSON text, hence we omit JSON marshaling in it!)*

With this, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1sX3GuPrpyW)):

```
array ["100-10","200-20"] <nil>
map wtf? {"100-10":true,"200-20":true} <nil>
map must be: {"100-10":true, "200-20":true}
```

Note that `encoding.TextMarshaler` is enough as that is also checked when marsaling as values, not just for map keys. So you don't have to implement both `encoding.TextMarshaler` and [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler).

If you do implement both, you can have different output when the value is marshaled as a "simple" value and as a map key because `json.Marshaler` takes precedence when generating a value:

```
func (a Int) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    test := a / 100
    return json.Marshal(fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", a, test))
}

func (a Int) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    test := a / 10
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", a, test)), nil
}
```

This time the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nxEyRw94rgg)):

```
array ["100-1","200-2"] <nil>
map wtf? {"100-10":true,"200-20":true} <nil>
map must be: {"100-10":true, "200-20":true}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great but I've had to re-search for this enough times that I wanted to put a complete answer regarding marshal/unmarshal with examples so next time I can just copy paste as a starting point :)

The things I often search for include:

- encode custom type to sql database
- json encode enum int as string
- json encode map key but not value

In this example I make a custom Weekday type which matches time.Weekday int values but allows for the string value in request/response json and in the database

This same thing can be done with any int enum using iota to have the human readable value in json and database

**Playground example with tests**: https://go.dev/play/p/aUxxIJ6tY9K

The important bit is here though:

```golang
var (
    // read/write from/to json values
    _ json.Marshaler   = (*Weekday)(nil)
    _ json.Unmarshaler = (*Weekday)(nil)

    // read/write from/to json keys
    _ encoding.TextMarshaler   = (*Weekday)(nil)
    _ encoding.TextUnmarshaler = (*Weekday)(nil)

    // read/write from/to sql
    _ sql.Scanner   = (*Weekday)(nil)
    _ driver.Valuer = (*Weekday)(nil)
)

// MarshalJSON marshals the enum as a quoted json string
func (w Weekday) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"` + w.String() + `"`), nil
}

func (w Weekday) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(w.String()), nil
}

func (w *Weekday) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    return w.UnmarshalText(b)
}

func (w *Weekday) UnmarshalText(b []byte) error {
    var dayName string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &dayName); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    d, err := ParseWeekday(dayName)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *w = d
    return nil
}

// Value is used for sql exec to persist this type as a string
func (w Weekday) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return w.String(), nil
}

// Scan implements sql.Scanner so that Scan will be scanned correctly from storage
func (w *Weekday) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch t := src.(type) {
    case int:
        *w = Weekday(t)
    case int64:
        *w = Weekday(int(t))
    case string:
        d, err := ParseWeekday(t)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *w = d
    case []byte:
        d, err := ParseWeekday(string(t))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *w = d
    default:
        return errors.New("Weekday.Scan requires a string or byte array")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note that the var block simply forces you to implement the methods correctly else it won't compile.

Also note that if you exclude `MarshalJSON` then go will use `MarshalText` if it is there, so if you want only the key to have a custom marshal but to have the default behavior for the value then you should not use these methods on your main type, but instead have a wrapper type that you only use for map keys

```golang
type MyType struct{}
type MyTypeKey MyType
var (
    // read/write from/to json keys
    _ encoding.TextMarshaler   = (*MyTypeKey)(nil)
    _ encoding.TextUnmarshaler = (*MyTypeKey)(nil)
)
func (w MyTypeKey) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(w.String()), nil
}

func (w *MyTypeKey) UnmarshalText(b []byte) error {
    *w = MyTypeKey(ParseMyType(string(b)))
    return nil
}
```

Feel free to improve this answer, I hope others find it helpful and I hope I can find it again next time I want this and search for it again myself :)